# no function matches the given name and argument types. you might need to add explicit type casts. INSERT on PREPARE

Tags: plpgsql

I have this PL/pgSQL function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_employee_att(emp_id INT, att_time TIMESTAMP)
  RETURNS void AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM employee_att WHERE employee_id = emp_id AND time_stamp = att_time) THEN
    PREPARE prep_att (INT, TIMESTAMP) 
    AS INSERT INTO employee_att (employee_id, time_stamp) VALUES ($1, $2);
    EXECUTE prep_att (emp_id, att_time);
    END IF;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then if i execute this:

```
SELECT add_employee_att(35, '2019-08-29 00:00:25'::timestamp);
```

I got this error:

```
Error in query: ERROR: function prep_att(integer, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT prep_att(emp_id, att_time)
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY: SELECT prep_att(emp_id, att_time)
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function add_employee_attendant(integer,timestamp without time zone) line 6 at EXECUTE
```

But if replace the PREPARE with this INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO employee_att (employee_id, time_stamp) VALUES (emp_id, att_time);
```

It works fine. Any idea what's wrong on the PREPARE stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `PREPARE` in `plpgsql`. It has not sense. Any embedded SQL is already prepared (execution plan is reused).

So write just

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_employee_att(emp_id INT, att_time TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM employee_att
                WHERE employee_id = emp_id 
                  AND time_stamp = att_time)
THEN
  INSERT INTO employee_att (employee_id, time_stamp) VALUES (emp_id, att_time);
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Attention: this test is example of typical code that is partially useless. It is not protection against duplicates `(emp_id, att_time)`. Only unique index is it. You cannot to know ever, if you see last data. Every time, when you are using SQL, you are working with snapshot of database. But data inside database can be little bit different already.